# How to terminate the users and update the label of the current users remaining?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, terminate

I have created members and stored them into the Database. I have a label which count all the users stored in the database,every time you save the numbers will increase. I also have a terminate button which terminate by the policy number, so this is what i want. When you terminate the member,it must also update the current members from the label. E.g Total members = 10 and when you terminate the user, the Total members label must also get updated to 9. How can i go it?

This is what i have done so far..

1. Loading total members

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lblTotal.Text = "Total Members Captured : " + CountMembersCaptured();
   }
   ```
2. Method for total members

   ```
   protected int CountMembersCaptured()
   {
       List<SP_COUNTPOLICYMEMBERSResult> _MemberCountList = _dc.SP_COUNTPOLICYMEMBERS().ToList();
       return _MemberCountList.Count();
   }
   ```
3. Procedure for getting total members

   ```
      ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_COUNTPOLICYMEMBERS]
      AS
      BEGIN        
      SELECT  [DateID]
     ,[PolicyNumber]
     ,[Name]
     ,[PolicyName]
     ,[InceptionDate]
     ,[Active]   
     FROM [dbo].[tblPolicy]
     END
   ```
4. Terminate button

   ```
   protected void btnTerminate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       if (Session["DateID"] != null)
       {
           List<tblPolicy> _PolicyMemberList = _dc.tblPolicies.Where(a => a.DateID == int.Parse(Session["DateID"].ToString())).ToList();

           if (_PolicyMemberList != null)
           {
               if (_PolicyMemberList.Count() > 0)
               {
                   foreach (tblPolicy _PolicyMember in _PolicyMemberList)
                   {
                       _PolicyMember.Active = false;
                   }

                   _dc.SubmitChanges();
                   lblresults.Text = "Confirmation: Member has been terminated/deleted successfully.!";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What are the possible values of `active` column in `tblPolicy` table?

Comment: The value is 1 because it is active. so when you terminate it disable and the value will be 0. data type is bite for Active column

Comment: @JuniorLinq, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Where clause to the select Query.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_COUNTPOLICYMEMBERS]
   AS
   BEGIN        
   SELECT  [DateID]
  ,[PolicyNumber]
  ,[Name]
  ,[PolicyName]
  ,[InceptionDate]
  ,[Active]   
  FROM [dbo].[tblPolicy] where Active=1
  END
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_COUNTPOLICYMEMBERS]
AS
BEGIN        
SELECT  [DateID]
,[PolicyNumber]
,[Name]
,[PolicyName]
,[InceptionDate]
,[Active]   
FROM [dbo].[tblPolicy] WHERE [Active]=1
END

protected void btnTerminate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (Session["DateID"] != null)
{
    List<tblPolicy> _PolicyMemberList = _dc.tblPolicies.Where(a => a.DateID == int.Parse(Session["DateID"].ToString())).ToList();

    if (_PolicyMemberList != null)
    {
        if (_PolicyMemberList.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (tblPolicy _PolicyMember in _PolicyMemberList)
            {
                _PolicyMember.Active = false;
            }

            _dc.SubmitChanges();
            lblresults.Text = "Confirmation: Member has been terminated/deleted successfully.!";
            lblTotal.Text = "Total Members Captured : " + CountMembersCaptured();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't update the label..it remains the same. I have done what you told me.

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

Comment: Are you getting any exception ? otherwise its code working correctly.

Comment: I did debug and am not getting any exception..Yes,the code works fine as it update the label every time i save

Comment: Debug user terminate button click code it's working good or not.

Comment: I have just debug  btnTerminate_Click and am not getting any exception. I did quick watch and still the number didn't change. I don't know what seems to be the problem thou